# Error de importación de css en Html en Plesk

Tags: css, font-awesome, plesk

tengo este problema al importar librerias por cdn o ruta especifica me arroja el siguiente:

Ejemplo al importar fontawesome de esta manera

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Me arroja un error así:´

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me sale un DOCTYPE html lo cual me produce un error en el estilo de la pagina. Alguien sabe por que pasa esto?
Estoy usando Plesk Obsidian 18.0.36, en apache no me pasaba esto.

Comment: Plesk usa Apache como servidor de páginas. Quizás tengas algo mal configurado. He probado CDN que pones de fontAwesome y funciona perfectamente, también en un servidor gestionado con Plesk. La primera cuestión es si en local tienes el mismo error.

Comment: En local tengo el mismo error, uso Plesk en Windows Server 2016, no he podido solucionar esto.

Comment: ¿En local también tienes Plesk? ¿Puedes poner la url de una página publicada? Sigo sin entender el error.

Comment: Gracias amigo, mira habilite esta url http://162.215.215.100/plesk-site-preview/erp.controlantilemu.cl/cost-center   Si te fijas al ver el código fuente o inspeccionar en la linea 49 o 50 se repite el DOCTYPE htm